# Parsing html in Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am trying to parse html tags here using jsoup. I am new to jsoup. Basically I need to parse the  tags and get the text inside those tags and apply the style mentioned in the class attribute.

I am creating a SpannableStringBuilder for that I can create substrings, apply styles and append them together with texts that have no styles.

```
String str = "There are <span class='newStyle'> two </span> workers from the <span class='oldStyle'>Front of House</span>";

SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    if (value.contains("</span>")) {
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(value);
        Elements elements = document.getElementsByTag("span");
        if (elements != null) {
            int i = 0;
            int start = 0;
            for (Element ele : elements) {
                String styleName =  type + "." + ele.attr("class");
                text.append(ele.text());
                int style = context.getResources().getIdentifier(styleName, "style", context.getPackageName());
                text.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(context, style), start, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                text.append(ele.nextSibling().toString());
                start = text.length();
                i++;
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
```

I am not sure how I can parse the strings that are not between any tags such as the "There are" and "worker from the".

Need output such as:

```
- There are
- <span class='newStyle'> two </span>
- workers from the
- <span class='oldStyle'>Front of House</span>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594261/how-to-extract-tags-and-text-between-tags-to-a-list-with-jsoup/59596051#59596051

Comment: @KrystianG: thanks for that. From a node how can I get the text stripping the html , like the text "two" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full answer: you can get the text outside of the tags by getting `childNodes()`. This way you obtain `List<Node>`. Note I'm selecting `body` because your HTML fragment doesn't have any parent element and parsing HTML fragment with jsoup adds `<html>` and `<body>` automatically.
If `Node` contains only text it's of type `TextNode` and you can get the content using `toString()`.
Otherwise you can cast it to `Element` and get the text using`element.text()`.

```
    String str = "There are <span class='newStyle'> two </span> workers from the <span class='oldStyle'>Front of House</span>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
    Element body = doc.selectFirst("body");
    List<Node> childNodes = body.childNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.size(); i++) {
        Node node = body.childNodes().get(i);
        if (node instanceof TextNode) {
            System.out.println(i + " -> " + node.toString());
        } else {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            System.out.println(i + " -> " + element.text());
        }
    }
```

output:

```
0 -> 
There are 
1 -> two
2 ->  workers from the 
3 -> Front of House
```

By the way: I don't know how to get rid of the first line break before `There are`.

Comment: thanks, I used Parser.xmlParser to avoid the tags Jsoup adds.